LEDs forward voltage at minimum brightness
I have a design issue. My circuit connects its MCU 5 V supply to two of these green LEDs in series with a 170 Ω current limiting resistor. I'm stuck with using two of the LEDs in series. I don't need them to be bright, just lit.
The LED forward voltage drop at 20 mA is 3.1..3.7 V, though the forward voltage drops at lower currents. The datasheet graph shows that the LEDs will operate below 2.5 V.
What is interesting is that the voltage drop across the 170 Ω resistor is about 150 mV so the LED current is <1 mA. If I increase the resistor to 6 kΩ, the LEDs are still lit. (They go completely off with 500 kΩ.) If I use 10 Ω instead, the current goes above 1 mA but, for some reason, the LED's voltage drop seems to decrease slightly to 2.4 V.
I've had them with a 170 Ω resistor and they've been working for weeks now. My questions are:

Will the only thing that could turn the LEDs off completely be the 5 V supply dropping below, say, 4.5..4.6 V?

To keep them on with a lower supply, should I changes the resistor to, say, 10 Ω or just have no resistor at all.



Please explain what your design issue is.

Are you saying that with 170 ohms and two LEDs in series you are getting 0.15 V across the 170 Ohm resistor?  And that if you use 6 kOhm in series with both LEDs that you can still see both of them, visibly, at about 25 microamps each? And what you write about using 10 Ohms just adds more mystery. Your writing isn't clear enough for me. Show pictures, write more.

If you worry about overloading the MCU pin by decreasing the limiting resistor then drive them via a transistor instead.

The problem with voltage-driving LEDs, which is what you are effectively doing, is that the LED forward voltage varies with temperature. This could explain your anomolous voltage readings, which reduce when they are carrying more current, and so are hotter.
If you want predictable LED performance, drive them with a current source. If your current source is simply a resistor in series with a voltage source, then have at least 1 V across the resistor, to swamp voltage variations from the LED.
At the low currents you seem happy to use, then using them singly with 2.5 V across the dropper resistor would not use much more current than at present, and would allow you to predict what the current would be, and whether they are on or off, regardless of the MCU's power supply tolerances.

Thank you @Neil_UK. The thing is I'm stuck with these led in series, this the issue. I don't need them bright at all just ON. If vf goes low with temp, and the foward current reaches 20ma at 3.1-3.7 vf. If let say I leave them without a resitor in theory this will not reach more than 20ma, if the max voltage at the pin tolerances is 5.3v. If i place a 10 ohms will "limt" the cureent.The 170 ohms I put there is very small current below 1ma, volatge at the end is 0.150v and don't stop turning ON even at5-6k. I know this not ideal at all but I'm stuck here, I just care to have the "best" case.

@Citi If you are stuck with two LEDs, and happy with unpredictable current, then no resistor, 10 ohms, 170 ohms, all give you roughly the same result. By the way. 'best' is spelt 'least worst'! Just don't put excess voltage on your MCU, or switch the green LEDs for red ones.

You have an MCU -- use your microcontroller as a voltage doubler or tripler. Since you only want to ensure the dimmest illumination, not brightness, this is perfect.
Dave Jones of EEVblog fame has an episode for this (if you need it):
EEVBlog #473 – Microcontroller Voltage Doubler or the straight YouTube version.
Here's what I have in mind:
This is a voltage doubler from a 25 KHz, 5 volt, 50% square wave, and can light the LED's down to 3.3 volts. Here's the Falstad Voltage Doubler Link. Five volts delivers about 5.0mA, so you may need to decrease the frequency if you want to keep the green LED's dim.

This is a voltage tripler from a 25 KHz, 5 volt, 50% square wave, and can light the LED's down to 2.5 volts. Here's the Falstad Voltage Tripler Link. Five volts delivers about 7.5mA, so you may need to decrease the frequency if you want to keep the green LED's dim.

Of course you can bit-bang the square wave and its frequency to provide exactly what you want -- brighter, dimmer, constant-brightness, etc.
As the voltage of the battery falls, you can increase the frequency of the square wave to compensate and provide the same level of illumination. Since you want it barely lit, this may be critical, because as the battery voltage falls, the LED's at dimmest brightness will go out if you don't compensate.

As Neil_UK said in his comment, you can keep the two LEDs in series with no resistor (or a zero ohm jumper instead of a resistor) or 10 ohms, it won't make much difference.
5V is already less than the typical voltage of the two LED series (6.2V) so they already use very little current. You can add some resistance (100 Ohms or 1K) to further decrease current consumption.
The LED are still lit with relatively high series resistance because it takes really very very little current to lit such small SMD LEDs.
But the light output may be so dim that you won't see them in under strong light environment (i.e. day light). You will want to check this.
Yes, the only way to turn them off completely is to lower the voltage to less than a certain threshold, approximately 4V in this case.
To keep them on with a lower power supply, say, less than 4V, you will have to bypass one of the two LEDs. Removing the resistor won't help since input voltage is already too low.
You can replace one of the LEDs with a resistor or a zero ohm jumper with a compatible footprint.
Then it will work with any voltage >2.5V.
